# What does "keynote company" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ROBERT CIALDINI is ...Regents’ Professor Emeritus of Psychology and
>   Marketing at Arizona State University and president and CEO of
>   INFLUENCE AT WORK, a global training and keynote company.

I searched the word [keynote](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keynote) and found that it means:

> the main point in a book, system of beliefs, activity etc that
>   influences everything else.

But I don't understand the meaning of "keynote company" exactly. Does it  symply mean " the main company"?

Can we reword the phrase "a global training and keynote company" to "a global and keynote company for training"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "Keynote speech" is a speech that sets out the central theme of a conference.  Typically the conference organisers will hire a well known or important person in the field to give the keynote speech.

You can hire Robert Caldini to give a Keynote speech. This is one of the ways his company makes money.  " A global training and keynote company" is a company that conducts training and keynote speeches around the world.

So you can't rephrase to "Global keynote company for training".

Comment: how would you interpret "a global training and keynote company"? a company that conducts training and keynotes around the world?

Comment: Exactly.  'Ive edited to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Keynote is nowadays also use as a noun into companies to express for instance a monthly meeting were all employees are welcome in order to adress a review of the past month and celebrate for instances best employees or the month etc..

> Apple officially unveiled the iPhone Class of 2018 during its annual **keynote** event on Wednesday. [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keynote#synonyms)

As you can see above a keynote can also be public in order to promote a new product.

In **conclusion** a keynote is basically a presentation so "a global training and keynote company" could be interpreted as:

> a company that is world-wide recognized for they famous **trainings** and
>   astonishing **presentations**

Comment: how would you interpret "a global training and keynote company"? a company that conducts training and keynotes globally?

Comment: To make it simple a keynote is basically a presentation so to answer you I would interpret it as "a company that is world-wide recognized for they famous trainings and astonishing presentations"

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I would simply interpret it as "Robert Cialdini has an inflated view of his own self-importance". But then, I usually err on the side of cynicism. However https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cialdini doesn't make me want to change my mind.